# select strings between two words in KornShell

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, grep, ksh

I want to select only matching string from a line.
Here is my test string:

- "I am using basic grep expression."

I want the string which starts from "am" and ends with "express". But in the above mentioned line my ending word is not there, instead of that "expression" is there.
I used following command for that.
`echo 'I am using basic grep expression.' | sed -n "s/.*\(am.*express\).*/\1/p"`

But it gives like this,

- "am using basic grep express"

Ideally it should not give any output as per my requirement. Can any one suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *word anchors* to your regex:

```
grep -o '\<am\>.*\<express\>' <<END
I am using basic grep expression.
END
```

That command produces no output.

The zero-length anchor `\>` will only match when the character to the left is a "word character" (alpha, digit, underscore) and the char to the right is a "non-word character". Similar for `\<`

ref http://man.cx/regexp(5)

---

If you don't have GNU grep, perl will work well

```
perl -lne 'print $1 while /(\bam\b.*?\bexpress\b)/g' <<END
I am using basic grep expression.
but here I am in the express lane at the grocery store and am further on express time.
not here
END
```

```
am in the express
am further on express
```

Comment: Hi..I tried your code as follows ..but it is not working. Can u please look into it..

Comment: echo "I am using basic grep expression" | grep '\<am\>.*\<expression\>'

Comment: In HP UNIX grep -o is not there.So can u please suggest a alternative for this.

Comment: I somehow missed your comments. Updated answer

Comment: Hi..is it possible to get the first occurrence of 'am in the express'

Comment: I don't understand your question: you *do* get "am in the express".

Comment: Sorry, i want the first occurrence of text between am and express.That is only "am in the express" not "am further on express"

Comment: `perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\bam\b.*?\bexpress\b)/'`

Comment: What??? what exactly do you want to see? only the first match or all matches? I've given you both

Comment: Hi actually the second code that you have given is printing both things not the first occurrence.My requirement is to take each occurrence and save it to an array.can you please help me.

Comment: Also the code considers only if the particular pattern exist in the same line.If the starting pattern exists in one line and ending pattern exists in another line it is not considering.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    undef $/;               # Enable 'slurp' mode
    open (FILE, '<', 'sample.txt') or die "Could not open sample.txt: $!";

    my $file = <FILE>;      # Whole file here now...
    my ($stuff_that_interests_me) = 
         ($file =~ m/.*?(Some text.*?End of text that I want to capture).*/s);
    print "$stuff_that_interests_me\n";
    close (FILE) or die "Could not close sample.txt: $!";

Comment: the above code gives the first occurence ..how to get the next occurrences

Comment: I want to store each occurrence to an array

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'I am using basic grep expression.' | sed ...
```

depend of your meaning:

- whole line start with `am` and end with `express`

  sed -n "/^am.*express$/ p"
- contain `am` and followed later with `express`

  sed -n "/am.*express/ p"

on several line (2 max in this case)

```
sed -n "/^am/ {
   /am.*express$/ {p;b}
: more
   N
   /am.*express$/ {p;b}
   s/.*\n//
   /am/ b more
   }"
```

To test especially with a express on last line of file with more than 3 line

Comment: thank you...But my problem is, the word 'express' is in next line.Can you suggest a solution for this.